# Strange Crash, No Debugger Clues

Tags: objective-c, debugging, crash, cocos2d-iphone

I am currently running this Block of code in my Level1.m file, this is the scene for the first level of my game.

```
#import "BankerL1.h"
#import "GameOverScene.h"
#import "BankerGameWin1.h"

// HelloWorldLayer implementation
@implementation BankerL1Layer
@synthesize label = _label;
@synthesize Banker = _Banker;
@synthesize WalkAction = _WalkAction;
@synthesize MoveAction = _MoveAction;

+(CCScene *) scene
{
// 'scene' is an autorelease object.
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

// 'layer' is an autorelease object.
BankerL1Layer *layer = [BankerL1Layer node];

// add layer as a child to scene
[scene addChild: layer];

// return the scene
return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
// always call "super" init
// Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
if( (self=[super init])) {

    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Ninja Menu Background.png"];
    background.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    [self addChild:background z:-1];

    CCLabelTTF *Levelcounter = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Level 1" fontName:@"Marker         Felt" fontSize:40];
    Levelcounter.position =  ccp(winSize.width * 0.80,winSize.height * 0.92);
    [self addChild: Levelcounter];

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:     @"GreenorcSpriteSheet_default.plist"];

    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode     batchNodeWithFile:@"GreenorcSpriteSheet_default.png"];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];

    NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i <=6; ++i) {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject: [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]     spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Greenorc%d.png", i]]];

    }
    CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];
    self.Banker = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Greenorc1.png"];
    _Banker.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, (winSize.height/2)-190);
    self.WalkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate     actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
    //[_Banker runAction:_WalkAction];
    [spriteSheet addChild:_Banker];

    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

    _targets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}
return self;
}

- (void) onEnter
{
// First, call super if you override this. ALWAYS.
[super onEnter];

[self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:1.5];
[self scheduleUpdate]; // use this instead of schedule: if it's for an update method.

}

//Implements the Callback function above
-(void)gameLogic:(ccTime)dt {
[self addTarget];

}

-(void)spriteMoveFinished:(id)sender {
CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)sender;
[self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];

if (sprite.tag == 1) { // target
    [_targets removeObject:sprite];

    GameOverScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverScene node];
    [gameOverScene.layer.label setString:@"You Lose :["];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameOverScene];

} else if (sprite.tag == 2) { // projectile
    [_targets removeObject:sprite];
}
}

//Adds the "targets" or in this case enemies, to the scene and spawns/moves them
-(void)addTarget {

CCSprite *target = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"seeker.png"
rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];

target.tag = 1;
[_targets addObject:target];

// Determine where to spawn the target along the X axis
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
int minX = target.contentSize.height/2;
int maxX = winSize.height - target.contentSize.height/2;
int rangeX = maxX - minX;
int actualX = (arc4random() % rangeX) + minX;//Randomizes the place it will spawn on X-    Axis

// Create the target slightly off-screen along the top edge,
// and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above
target.position = ccp(actualX, winSize.height + (target.contentSize.height/2));
[self addChild:target];

// Determine speed of the target
int minDuration = 2.0;
int maxDuration = 5.0;
int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;//Speed is randomized     between 2 and 5

// Create the actions
id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration
                                    position:ccp(actualX, -target.contentSize.height/2)];
id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];
[target runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];

}

//WHEN THE THINGS COLLIDE, THEY DISSAPEAR
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

NSMutableArray *targetsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (CCSprite *target in _targets) {
    CGRect targetRect = CGRectMake(
                                       target.position.x - (target.contentSize.width/2),
                                       target.position.y - (target.contentSize.height/2),
                                       target.contentSize.width,
                                       target.contentSize.height);
    BOOL playerHit = FALSE;
    for (CCSprite *player in _targets) {
        CGRect playerRect = CGRectMake(
                                       player.position.x - (player.contentSize.width/2),
                                       player.position.y - (player.contentSize.height/2),
                                       player.contentSize.width,
                                       player.contentSize.height);

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(playerRect, targetRect)) {
            //[targetsToDelete addObject:target];
            playerHit = TRUE;
                [targetsToDelete addObject:target];

            break;
        }
    }

    for (CCSprite *target in targetsToDelete) {
        [_targets removeObject:target];
        [self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];

        _targetsDestroyed++;
        [_label setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
        if (_targetsDestroyed > 30) {
            GameWinScene *gameWinScene = [GameWinScene node];
            _targetsDestroyed = 0;
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameWinScene];
        } else{
            NSString *killcounttext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Catches: %i",     _targetsDestroyed];
            self.label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:killcounttext fontName:@"Zapfino"     fontSize:20];
            _label.color = ccc3(225,225,225);
            _label.position = ccp(winSize.width * 0.20,winSize.height * 0.92);
            [self addChild:_label];
        }
    }

    if (targetsToDelete.count > 0) {
        [targetsToDelete addObject:target];
    }
    [targetsToDelete release];
}

for (CCSprite *target in targetsToDelete) {
    [_targets removeObject:target];
    [self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];
    //[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"ProjectileHit.wav"];
}
[targetsToDelete release];
}

-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0
                                          swallowsTouches:YES];
}

-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
return YES;
}

-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];
touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

float bankerVelocity = 320.0/2.0;

CGPoint moveDifference = ccpSub(touchLocation, _Banker.position);

float distanceToMove = ccpLength(moveDifference);

float moveDuration = distanceToMove / bankerVelocity;

    if (moveDifference.x < 0) {
    _Banker.flipX = NO;
    } else {
    _Banker.flipX = YES;
    }

[_Banker stopAction:_MoveAction];

if (!_Moving) {
    [_Banker runAction:_WalkAction];
}
self.MoveAction = [CCSequence actions:
                   [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:moveDuration position:touchLocation],
                   [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(bearMoveEnded)],
                   nil];

[_Banker runAction:_MoveAction];
_Moving = TRUE;

}

-(void)bearMoveEnded {
[_Banker stopAction:_WalkAction];
_Moving = FALSE;
}

// on "dealloc" you need to release all your retained objects
- (void) dealloc
{
// in case you have something to dealloc, do it in this method
// in this particular example nothing needs to be released.
// cocos2d will automatically release all the children (Label)
self.Banker = nil;
self.WalkAction = nil;

// don't forget to call "super dealloc"
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

The scene starts and everything works fine except as soon as a target is added (this is what I think is happeneing) the game freezes and crashes.
I don't know if the target being added is what is causing the crash, but it seems that whenever it is time for the target to come on, it crashes.

There is nothing in the debugger that says the game crashed, Xcode things the game is still running even though it is frozen. Please help :/ thanks

Comment: Could you add some breakpoints, see where does it crash?

Comment: Have you tried hitting 'break' in the debugger and seeing what happens?  Your code might have gone into an infinite loop.

Comment: add a global exception breakpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

retain the `_targets` array in the `init` method like this: `_targets = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] retain];`

Comment: ...which will guarantee a leak when he tries to release it later. The _targets object now has a retain count of 2, instead of the expected retain count of 1 that [[<class> alloc] init] provides.

Comment: @gschandler he should retain the _targets array in order to get the ownership of it. If not, the system will automatically release the array and eventually deallocate it, which will result in a crash. It is right that if you log its retain count by calling `[_targets retainCount]` it will log 1, but `retainCount` is not reliable. In short, if you want an object to be around (you have the ownership of it), you should retain it. Please read the documentation about memory management.

Comment: @gschandler I guess you have voted down my answer. Please undo it

Comment: I added the retain like you mentioned in your origigonal answer, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: @ZeusAlexander I'm familiar with memory managment.  I added logs to the addtarget method and it got all the way to the end of it before crashing, so maybe that's not the issue? I'm really just not sure

Comment: _tagets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; already gives ownership to it. No need for an extra retain. Also, using -retainCount is not a reliable method for determining proper retain counts (as ironic as it may sound). If you don't believe me, please believe an actual Apple engineer, @bbum, who is pretty reliable at this subject: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/

Comment: I fixed it, I had the player and the target in the same array so i created a seperate array for each.